# Adding an Google Pay Button or a Custom Action in Google Scene Viewer

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, quicklook

do you know if there is any way how to implement Google Pay Button, go to cart button or custom action to Google Scene Viewer?

Basically I am interested if there is something similar like in Apple Quick Look  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_an_apple_pay_button_or_a_custom_action_in_ar_quick_look

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thank you very much

Kind Regards

Jan